# HTML: Controlling the number of characters per line in <pre> environment

Tags: html

I want the following code:

```
<pre style="voodoo">123456789</pre>
```

To display as:

```
123
456
789
```

(In general I have a huge chunk of text and I want to display exactly n chars in a line, where n is any number).

So I tried this:

```
<pre style="width:3em; word-wrap:break-word;">123456789</pre>
```

But em doesn't really work this way; and px as well. I there a unit which describes the font-width (especially in  environment)? Or is there another property I should change instead of width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of [<`pre`>][1] is to preserve formating (white space) which is the opposite of what you are trying to do! Although this seems to work for me

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word;width:60px">
12345678910123456789
</div>

<pre style="word-wrap: break-word;width:60px">
12345678910123456789
</pre>
```

Comment: `word-wrap:break-word;` makes browsers break words

Comment: the whole point of pre is to preserve formatting, maybe he should try a div instead

Comment: I don't think the problem is any different with div.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
pre {
    width: 2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N3cqb/).

Though I suspect that the perfect width, and the relationship between the number of characters per line and the width, seems to be somewhat arbitrary and found by trial and error. So while it works (at least in Chromium 17/Ubuntu 11.04), I'm not particularly happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually choose appropriate value of `width`, but I don't sure it will work same in all browsers/systems.

By the way `em` means "width of symbol m", so it should to do the work. But it doesn't, don't know why.

Comment: Although that is the original meaning of the term, that was at a time when all capital `M`s were square. Nowadays the `M` is usually somewhat less than one `em` wide.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work in Firefox, but I don't know about other browsers:

```
<pre wrap width="3" style="word-wrap:break-word;">123456789</pre>
<pre style="width: 3ch; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">123456789</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can count value for width use following formula

width = (coun of symbols per row)/1.5

for example

9 symbols per row / 1.5 = 6em

it will work if you don't use font-size-adjust

Comment: This does not work. For example, for 2em I get 4 letters in a row.